# Is it possible to enable cortana and keep my language?

Tags: windows-10, cortana

Is its possible to enable Cortana and keep other language settings as it is?

For example, Cortana will understand my English communication, but in Start and all other stuff I will have my normal language (Czech, German, etc.)